# Требуется перекодировать ANSI в UTF8

Tags: c++, кодировка, c++builder

Пишу мини-программу чтобы включить часть кода в основной проект.
Задача такая: требуется скопировать файл в память, там его конвертировать в UTF8 и уже дальше делать свои манипуляции (в рамках примера просто вывести полученный текст в компонент Memo1).

**Проблема**

1. Функции конвертации содержащиеся в заголовке *System.h* не работают. Например: функция *AnsiToUtf8()* вообще не выполняет свою задачу, не смотря на то что исходит из *System.h*.

```
void __fastcall TForm20::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  TFileOpenDialog* FOD = new TFileOpenDialog(this);                                                                                                                 
  TMemoryStream* MS = new TMemoryStream;                                                                                            
  
  if (FOD->Execute()) {
       AnsiString sourceFileName = FOD->FileName;                                                                              
       TFileStream* FS = new TFileStream(sourceFileName, fmOpenRead);
       
       MS->CopyFrom(FS, 0);                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
       delete FS;
       MS->Position = 0;
       
     //*******
       AnsiToUtf8(MS->ToString()); //внимание на эту строку
     //*******

       TStreamReader* SR = new TStreamReader(MS,TEncoding::UTF8);   
       Memo1->Lines->Add(SR->ReadToEnd());
       
       delete SR;
}

delete MS;
delete FOD;
}
```

Если попытаться открыть файл кодировки UTF-8 - то всё откроется и добавится в Memo1, но при попытке открыть файл кодировки ANSI появляется ошибка:

> Project Project15.exe raised exception class EEncodingError with message 'No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page'.

Если в выделенной звёздочками строке попытаться использовать другие функции, по типу *UTF8Encode(MS->ToString())* или же *UTF8Decode(MS->ToString())* - ситуация не изменится.

2. Функции из подключаемых заголовков, по типу *<WideStrUtils.hpp>*, студия воспринимает как не существующие. Пример тому - *ConvertStreamFromAnsiToUTF8()*. В документации о ней сказано следующе:

> extern DELPHI_PACKAGE void __fastcall ConvertStreamFromAnsiToUTF8(System::Classes::TStream* Src, System::Classes::TStream* Dst, int cp = 0x0);

> Converts a stream from ANSI to UTF-8 encoding.
> ConvertStreamFromAnsiToUTF8 converts an input stream specified by Src to an output stream specified by Dst. The function assumes that the input stream contains text encoded in ANSI and converts it to UTF-8. Optionally, the code page of the input ANSI stream is specified.
> If the specified code page is CP_UTF8 then a direct copy is made; otherwise a conversion is performed.

Не знаю уже что делать дальше.

P.S: вариант с сохранением в файл не пойдёт, нужно именно внутри памяти всё делать, того требуют условия. Благодарю заранее за помощь!

P.P.S если попробовать:

```
String str = MS->ToString();
```

В переменной будет записан просто тип данных в виде строки "TMemoryStream".
То же самое произойдет если это все обернуть так:

```
String str = (AnsiToUtf8(MS->ToString));
```

Даже если str будет иметь тип UnicodeString

Comment: Приведенные мной методы работают в билдере (если он не сильно старый)

Answer (score 0):

Вы пишете

```
 AnsiToUtf8(MS->ToString()); //внимание на эту строку
```

А чему присвоен результат функции?

Вообще `ms->ToString`  **Returns a string containing the class name** - это явно не то, то вы хотели - извлечь тело стрима как строку. Вы можете сделать строку из `ms->Memory`, но для текста ведь всё проще:

Сделал текст `qwerФЫВАпрол` в блокноте, сохранил в три файла с кодировкой ANSI, UTF8, Unicode. Длина соответственно 12,23,26 байт (в UTF и Unicode есть BOM-маркер).
Прочитал в Delphi указанным ниже образом, всё правильно вывелось. Преобразовал ANSI строку в UTF8, тоже правильно определилась кодировка, но её можно и указать вручную в   `AnsiToUtf8Ex(s, 1251);` (из `System.WideStrUtils`)

```
...System.IOUtils, System.WideStrUtils

var
  s: string;
begin

  s := TFile.ReadAllText('E:\uni.txt', TEncoding.Unicode);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  s := TFile.ReadAllText('E:\utf.txt', TEncoding.UTF8);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  s := TFile.ReadAllText('E:\ansi.txt', TEncoding.ANSI);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  s := AnsiToUtf8(s);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);

qwerФЫВАпрол
qwerФЫВАпрол
qwerФЫВАпрол
qwerФЫВАпрол
```

Comment: Строка `qwerФЫВАпрол` не может быть в ANSI кодировке. Ну и вопрос про билдер, при чем тут делфи.

Comment: @user7860670 Библиотека одна и та же. А про `не может быть` я, видимо, что-то не понял. Видимо, вы имеет в виду 128 символов стандартного ANSI, а я ANSI 1251

Comment: Не знаю, одна у них там библиотека или нет, но язык отличается от указанного в вопросе. ANSI кодировка не предполагает хранения кириллицы.

Comment: @user7860670 Вы, видимо, имеете в виду нерасширенный набор ASCII (я в прошлом комменте неправильно назвал). Под ANSI кодировками [обычно имеется в виду](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Windows_code_page&action=view&section=6#Windows-125x_series) неофициальное название однобайтных (кроме японцев) Windows-125x кодировок (кодовая страницаCP-1251 для русского). Однако это неофициальное название употребляется практически повсеместно (например, в MS Windows Notepad)